# .htaccess rewrite rule to prevent image url rewrites

Tags: .htaccess

I am very new to htaccess rewrite rules. I need to rewrite the url `myurl.com/1000/samsung-123` to `myurl.com/user/product.php?id=1000`. I have used the following rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/(.*)$ user/product.php?id=$1 [PT,L]
```

The rule works fine. However it also rewrites my images url like `myurl.com/img/_product/1000/1000A.jpg`.

How can I prevent this one? Is there a way to skip the rule if extension (as `.jpg`, `.png`, `.php`) is entered in the url?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond img/_product/$1/$1A.jpg !-f
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/(.*)$ user/product.php?id=$1 [PT,L]
```

Perhaps that will help.

- Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to skip static files. This will allow not only images, but also stylesheets, scripts and so on that you might use.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/(.*)$ user/product.php?id=$1 [PT,L]
```